# Is there any way to check if the declared type of a method parameter were consistent with the declared generic type?

Tags: python, generics

Consider a `generic type` baseclass:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Reader(ABC, Generic[S]):

    @abstractmethod
    def get_resource(self) -> S:
       pass
```

Also let's set up some dummy classes for trying this out:

```
class ResourceA():
    def uri(self) -> str:
        return "uri:ResourceA"

class ResourceB():
    def uri(self) -> str:
        return "uri:ResourceB"
```

Now let's cause some nonsense and mayhem. Yet no warnings/notifications are provided!

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

from typing_extensions import override


class Resource:

    @abstractmethod
    def uri(self) -> str:
        raise NotImplementedError

class ResourceA(Resource):
    @override
    def uri(self) -> str:
        return "uri:ResourceA"

class ResourceB(Resource):
    @override
    def uri(self) -> str:
        return "uri:ResourceB"

class ResourceC(Resource):
    @override
    def uri(self) -> str:
        return "uri:ResourceC"

S = TypeVar("S", bound=Resource)


class Reader(ABC, Generic[S]):

    @abstractmethod
    def get_resource(self) -> S:
       pass
    
class ReaderA(Reader[ResourceA]):
    
    def __init__(self, resource: ResourceA):
        self.resource = resource

    @override
    def get_resource(self) -> ResourceA:
        return self.resource # Incorrect on purpose to kick tires on warnings
        
class ReaderB(Reader[ResourceB]):

    def __init__(self, resource: ResourceA):
        self.resource = resource

    @override
    def get_resource(self) -> ResourceA: # incorrect on purpose to kick tires
        return self.resource
```

Now let's send in some messy stuff..

```
fr1 = ReaderA(ResourceB())
print('resourceA', fr1.get_resource().uri())

fr2 = ReaderB(ResourceC())
print('resourceB', fr2.get_resource().uri())
```

We get only the following output:

```
resourceA uri:ResourceB
resourceB uri:ResourceC
```

I realize these are generic type **hints** but still.. is there not some way to at least be *notified* /warned of the typing mismatch?  This is after all a compile time visibility situation.

Comment: "I realize these are generic type hints but still.. is there not some way to at least be notified /warned of the typing mismatch? This is after all a compile time visibility situation." No. Not unless you use something like `mypy` or `pyright` etc etc. This is critical to understand, your type hints will never be checked at runtime automatically. Python is a **dynamically typed language** and type hints don't change that. If you want static type checking, then *you need to use a static type checker*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  You can make an answer on that . For the _static type checker_ what are you suggesting there?  Is there such a thing for python or are you referring to only other languages [/dialects of python such as _mypy_] ?

Comment: So, [`mypy`](https://github.com/python/mypy) is not a dialect of python, it is a tool which runs static analysis on your code and reports type errors. Same as [`pyright`](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright). Those are probably the most common, along with the one that comes with the PyCharm IDE.